# Problems with building OpenCv with Xcode. Cannot find opencv2/opencv.hpp file

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv3.0

I have installed OpenCv with Homebrew on my MacOs. I have added libopencv 4.0.1.dylib in Xcode. When I try to build, Xcode cannot find the files. Any suggestions?

I changed my path but still have problems.

#### Main code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

#### Build settings including path:

[image]

#### Error messages:

[image]

Comment: Please include code as text rather than as image. [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: You should [edit] your question instead of posting additional information as comment.

Comment: I have added the code now